# CSS Div Positioning - Breaks wrapper height

Tags: css

I am having an unusual problem while positioning divs inside other divs, I have my main, a child and two ( grandchilds ), Now for the height of the child to adjust to the grandchild i have positioned them via float, Float left and float right,and my child is positioned absolute, now my main has a width of 980px and is centred with margin 0 auto, everything seems to work fine... I have noticed my main does not have a height it is at 0px, the child is fine, height adjusts to the floats properly etc but my min has no height, if i take it out the positioning goes to the left of the screen, How would i get the main to recognise the child, which then recognises the grandchildren, Please help i have tried clear: both and clear: auto to no avail

CSS:

```
#wrapper {

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;

}

#wall {

    width: 980px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;    

}

#left {

    width: 610px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;

}
#leftimg {

    border-radius: 35px;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 8px;

}
#right {

    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 310px;
    left: 645px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;

}

footer {

    text-align: center;
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <h1>Top Tips for your C.V</h1>
    <p>Follow these tips, No messing straight to the point</p>
    <img src="web-pics/check.png" alt="checksheet"/>

    <nav>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="wall">

        <div id="right">

            <h2><u>Interactive</u></h2>

        <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa
        aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
        aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa
        aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
        aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
        aaa
        </p>            

        </div>


        <div id="left">
        <h1><u>Why do we need a CV?</u></h1>

            <img src="web-pics/despair.jpg" alt="Despair" id="leftimg" />

            <p>

                Believe it or not, some people do not actually have a C.V, They believe that it is too much effort
                and that it is not worth the time putting one together. Well this could not be further from the truth,
                Indeed an employer will only look at your C.V briefly, so you may ask yourself what is the point in putting
                all that information on there if they are not going to read it properly. An employer is looking for something
                that will catch their eye, then they skim it over a little bit more, they look at your previous experience,
                and if they are still looking, they will want your contact details. A C.V is the first potential step into employment,
                Get this right and you may have yourself an Interview.                  

            </p>

            <h2><u>C.V Layout</u></h2>

            <p>

                The most important thing about your C.V is not so much the content, but how you have your layout.
                This is at least to start with, Remember that it needs to catch the eye of the person reading it.
                Unless you are applying for a role as a graphic designer, do not insert pictures, colours or other
                funny gimmicks, it needs to catch their eye and look professional. Use the page to your advantage though,
                The paper is white, the font is black, this can be a dull setting to start off with, why can't you add any
                colour to it, Think of it like this, you can add as much colour to it and images and other funny captions,
                but if the content is not as fulfilling as the colours, Then the employer may wish to employ someone who has
                taken the time to make their C.V Content an easier read, it can be difficult to read a C.V if it has clashing colours.

            </p>


        </div>


     </div>

</div>


<footer>
<br />
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
```

```
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought i would mention as Ricky Goldman stated,a container using position:absolute will not have the height recognized, I managed to achieve what i wanted by using position:relative for the wrapper and float for containers, and then in the footer i used clear:both please see CSS that follows. This got me the desired effect i was after. Thanks guys....

```
#wrapper {

margin: 0 auto;
width: 980px;
position: relative;}

#wall {

width: 980px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
border-radius: 50px;
float: left;}

#left {

width: 610px;
padding: 15px;
float: left;
background-color: white;}

#leftimg {

border-radius: 35px;
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
padding: 8px;}


#right {

width: 310px;
left: 645px;
padding: 5px;
float: right;
background-color: white;} 



footer {

text-align: center;
clear: both;}
```

Hope this may help someone else and thanks guys

Comment: Can you make this as the answer so the question appears to be answered?

Answer (score 0):

2 options depending on your need either could work.

```
#main { overflow: hidden }
```

This causes a sort of reset to the container boundaries when it renders and it will then recognize the floated children. Or...

```
#main { float: left }
```

If an item is floated, it will recognize its floated children when forming the boundaries of the box.  float: right would work also; the side doesn't matter.

Comment: I have tried both of them and it doesnt seem to work for me. The problem seems to be that the wrapper div is not recognising the wall div

Comment: can you please post your html?

Comment: I did not realize you were referring to wall since your post mentioned floats.  The container will not recognize the height of an absolute positioned element.  If you can do it without position: absolute, it will find the height.

Comment: I need to use absolute, so #right will adjust the height properly without needing to use overflow tag, any ideas?

Comment: Wall is the only child of #wrapper, so there should be no reason #wall has to be positioned absolute.  If you need #wrapper to be the same size as wall, make #wrapper position: absolute, but make #wall position: relative or static.  Then container will have the same size as wall.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to solve my problem, leading from the advice you gave

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple clearfix to your `div` that has no height (generally a container with floated children):

```
#wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Where `#wrapper` is the CSS selector for your zero-height div.